# pythonanywhere: access denied for user 'USERNAME'@'%' to database

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

I am using [www.pythonanywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com) for deployment of my Django project. The pythonanywhere's database settings are as follows:

```
Connecting: 
    Database host address: mysql.server
    Username: Username (just as an example)

Your databases:
    Start a console on: Username$DBName  (just as an example)
    ...
```

While setting up the database using "manage.py migrate" command, The error message showed up:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1044 "Access denied for user 'Username'@'%' to database 'DBName'")
```

DATABASES settings in file `settings.py` are as follows.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'DBName',
        'USER': 'Username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'mysql.server',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

I am able to run mysql in the Console using the command:

```
$ mysql -u Username -h mysql.server -p
```

When I enter the following command:

```
mysql> use mysql;
```

I got the error message:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'Username'@'%' to database 'mysql'
```

"show databases;" command shows there is no database named "mysql".

When I enter the following command:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DBName.* TO 'Username'@'Username$DBName' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I also got the error message:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'Username'@'%' to database 'DBName'
```

So, how do I setup the database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found this in the pythonanywhere documentation, the database settings to use MySQL should be of the form:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '<your_username>$<your_database_name>',
        'USER': '<your_username>',
        'PASSWORD': '<your_mysql_password>',
        'HOST': 'mysql.server',
    }
}
```

If your username is say user and database is db, then your database name should be **user$db**, not db.

Similarly, to access the database in the console you type

> mysql>use user$db;

and not

> mysql>use db;